# How to open another installed app with a onclick listener using Xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hello I am working on a app that has a button that has a onclick value assigned to it my question is how do I have it open another i have installed on the device I know how to do this in java but need to know how to do it in Xamarin

here's my button layout code:

```
<Button
            android:text="Tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:onClick="tools" />
```

here's my c# code to the button:

```
 //Code That Opens The Tools App!

    [Java.Interop.Export("tools")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
    public void btnOneClick2(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("com.d4a.toolbelt");
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

the com.d4a.toolbelt is the package name of the app i'm trying to open.

any help would be amazing!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out it works using this code:

```
 [Java.Interop.Export("tools")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick2(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {
            var intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.d4a.toolbelt");
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the PackageManager:

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = PackageManager;
try {
    i = manager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.d4a.toolbelt");
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    i.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryLauncher);
    StartActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! is this for Xamarin android using c# because i'm getting errors with the code snippet you gave me?

Comment: import the package: using Android.Content.PM;